# jquery append an element after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have an 2 objects, one contains supervisor and the other contains employee data and also the supervisor ID that corresponds to the employee(which will be used for the ul id). I wanted them to look like this below, using JQuery append:

- Supervisor A

  - Employee 1
  - Employee 2
- Supervisor B

  - Employee 3
  - Employee 4

or in HTML Form:

```
<ul id="myEmployee">
   <li> Supervisor A
      <ul id="supervisorA">
          <li id="employee1">Employee 1</li>
          <li id="employee2">Employee 2</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li> Supervisor B
      <ul id="supervisorB">
          <li id="employee3">Employee 3</li>
          <li id="employee4">Employee 4</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Initially I only have 
    `<ul id="myEmployee"></ul>`
to allow JQuery to append the elements.

Sample Data (as requested):

```
 supervisor = [{
     "SupervisorID": "SupervisorA",
     "DisplayName": "Supervisor A"
 }, {
     "SupervisorID": "SupervisorB",
     "DisplayName": "Supervisor B"
 }];

 employee = [{
     "SupervisorID": "SupervisorA",
     "employeeId": "employee1",
     "DisplayName": "Employee 1"
 }, {
     "SupervisorID": "SupervisorB",
     "employeeId": "employee2",
     "DisplayName": "Employee 2"
 }];
```

Using a for-loop, I first append the Supervisors first

```
for (let x = 0; x < supervisor.length; x++) {
   $('#myEmployee').append('<li>' + supervisor[x].DisplayName + '<ul id=' + supervisor[x].SupervisorID + '></ul></li>');
}
```

Here comes the problem, when i try to append the employees into the ul that contains the id of the supervisors using another for loop

```
for (let x = 0; x < employee.length; x++) {                
   $('#'+employee[x].SupervisorID).append('<li>' + employee[x].employeeID+'</li>');
}
```

Console told me that the JQuery could not find the ID of the ul that i have appended previously. In other words, jQuery thinks that the ul id was not initialised.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you show us the full code?

Comment: can you show sample data that you loop into

Comment: `employee.SupervisorID[x]` -> `employee[x].SupervisorID`, `employee.ID[x]` -> `employee[x].ID`

Comment: @guradio check my edit, I added the sample data.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for pointing out that minor error, but what I asked for is why doesnt the jQuery recognise the ul tag that i appended previously

Comment: The "minor" error (if it wasn't only a typo) should have caused a `TypeError`

Comment: The "supervisor" loop makes no sense. With this sample data `supervisor[x]` would be `[object Object]` and where is `supervisorID` in `'<ul id=' + supervisorID + '></ul></li>'` coming from?

Comment: I'll change that again. Sorry there are some things missing because I modified the code from the real project in order not to reveal too much stuff since there are some confidential stuff lying around in the project.

Comment: I agree with Andreas' last comment and would also recommend to use jquery's utility functions `$.map()` or `$.each()`. This leads - in my opinion - to better readable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/88k1bebo/)
You are accessing the objects in a wrong manner

First For Loop Fix :

```
 $('#myEmployee').append('<li>' + supervisor[x].DisplayName + '<ul id=' + supervisor[x].SupervisorID + '></ul></li>');
```

Second For loop Fix :

```
for (let x = 0; x < employee.length; x++) {                
   $('#'+employee[x].SupervisorID).append('<li>' + employee[x].employeeId+'</li>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand how JS arrays and objects work. First understand that and you'll see what went wrong.

Change the first loop to this:

```
for (let x = 0; x < supervisor.length; x++) {
   $('#myEmployee').append('<li>' + supervisor[x].DisplayName + '<ul id=' + supervisor[x].SupervisorID + '></ul></li>');
}
```

And second loop to this:

```
for (let x = 0; x < employee.length; x++) {                
   $('#'+employee[x].SupervisorID).append('<li id=' + employee[x].employeeID + '>' + employee[x].DisplayName+'</li>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The sample data you gave shows 2 arrays of objects, not 2 objects. You are also not accessing the array indexes and object keys correctly as @Andreas pointed out above.

Once you correct the code to access the arrays and objects within the jQuery should work.

```
for (let x = 0; x < supervisor.length; x++) {
    $('#myEmployee').append('<li>' + supervisor[x].DisplayName + '<ul id=' + supervisor[x].SupervisorID + '></ul></li>');
}

for (let x = 0; x < employee.length; x++) {                
   $('#' + employee[x].SupervisorID ).append('<li>' + employee[x].DisplayName + '</li>');
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/pjpwea/pLu5j3fh/2/